# Python Implement linked list in a class

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a class in python, each object will be a linked list. without using classes I can reverse a linked list like this

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 0
        self.next = None

def reverse(cur):
    if cur == None:
        return
    reverse(cur.next)
    print(cur.data,end =" ")

def printt(head):
    cur = head
    while cur is not None:
        print(cur.data, end =" ")
        cur = cur.next

def insert(head, data):
    cur = head 
    while cur.next!=None:
        cur = cur.next
    newnode = Node()
    newnode.data = data
    cur.next= newnode

head = Node()
for i in range(1,5):
    insert(head,i)
print("Complete list")
printt(head)
print()
print("reverse list")
reverse(head)
print()
print("head is ",head.data)

head = Node()
reverse(head)
```

Here a copy of head is passed to the reverse function.
I want to implement this in a class. Something I have tried.

```
class linked:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node()
    
    def reverse(self):
        while head:
           print(head.data)
           head = head.next
```

How can I pass self.head to the function reverse without losing the head pointer?
Thanks

Comment: did you try to use self.head instead of just head within the reverse function?

Comment: In this case, it would work, I gave a poor example, I have modified the question a bit. If a function is changing head pointer, how can I not lose the original head pointer?

Comment: Are you sure the first (non-class) code works? I haven't tried, but imagining the run, I have the feeling that it is just calling `reverse` on `node.next` without any effect and then stops..

Comment: @JanStránský Yes, it works. Please have a look at the complete code https://ideone.com/JfNuOG

Comment: Please put the complete code here

Comment: Working of my first approach is not my real question, but for clarity, I have shared the link, please try it there.

Comment: 1) please put the complete code **here**, shared link is fine, but it may be deleted or....
2) Working of your first approach **is** your real question. The code is **not** working. Just print once more `head` after `reverse`, it prints the original list (inside `reverse` it just `print` the values in reversed order, but leaves the list ontouched). Once you have *working* first approach, the second should be easy

Comment: @JanStránský Sir for clearity, I have added the code. Also I don't want to "REVERSE" the list, I just wanted to print it in the reversed order. My main question is how can I do it without manipulating the head pointer.

Comment: ok, sorry, next time please name your functions better, e.g. `printReversed` or something like that. just `reverse` suggest that the passed node(s) should be reversed..

Comment: Ok sir, can you answer my original question?

Comment: not 100% sure about it, but what about using a list (self.headers = []) and append the head pointers to it (self.headers.append(head.next)).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already working standalone functions, one approach is just to take them and use inside the class. Of course, you can also rewrite them to the class body.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 0
        self.next = None

def reverse(cur):
    if cur == None:
        return
    reverse(cur.next)
    print(cur.data,end =" ")

def printt(head):
    cur = head
    while cur is not None:
        print(cur.data, end =" ")
        cur = cur.next

def insert(head, data):
    cur = head 
    while cur.next!=None:
        cur = cur.next
    newnode = Node()
    newnode.data = data
    cur.next= newnode

class Linked:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node()
    def insert(self,data):
        insert(self.head,data)
    def reverse(self):
        reverse(self.head)
    def printt(self):
        printt(self.head)

linked = Linked()
for i in range(1,5):
    linked.insert(i)
print("Complete list")
linked.printt()
print()
print("reverse list")
linked.reverse()
print()
print("head is ",linked.head.data)
```